# PHP 7.1 connect to MSSQL NOT SQLSRV

Tags: sql-server, php-7.1

Anyone can help me how to use mssql in php 7.1 not sqlsrv because i like to try mssql because Im a new in programming.

Comment: The product is called SQL Server, neither MSSQL nor SQLSRV. Did you encounter a problem with a connection string or driver? Or did you confuse it with MySQL ?

Answer (score -2):

```
include 'connect.php';
$login_id = $_REQUEST['mobile_number'];
 $user_flag = $_REQUEST['user_flag'];

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
  if (!$con) {    die("could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());    
}
$sql =  "select * from login_details WHERE mobile_no = '$login_id' AND user_flag = '$user_flag'";

 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " .mysqli_error($con));

 while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $emparray[] = $row;
 }
 echo json_encode($emparray);

 mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: This is a question about *SQL Server*, not MySQL. Furthermore, this code is **extremely dangerous** because it exposes the application to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries, NOT interpolation or concatenation

Comment: check the title PHP 7.1 connect to MSSQL NOT SQLSRV

Comment: indeed, check the title. And the tags. And what happens if someone enters `'; drop table login_details;`  as a login id. Or `admin` as the username and `' OR 1=1` as the password. You should use parameterized queries, not string manipulation